# Disable status bar android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, statusbar, disable

Hi i want disable the status bar in an java app android, like when the user pull down the bar doesnt go down

Comment: There is no way to do that in a standard Android app.  That's a part of the system you can't mess with.  You can do it on a custom AOSP build if its your own hardware.  You used to be able to do it in a system app (which can't go in the play store), you may still be able to.  But not in a normal app.

Answer (score 0):

Hello bro use This one!

Use this code for hiding the status bar in your app and easy to use

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: This method is deprecated :\

Answer (score 0):

If what u want is full screen activity, use this

```java
public class sample extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setFullScreen();

        //add your code

    }

    private void setFullScreen() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
            getWindow().getInsetsController().hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() | WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
            getWindow().getInsetsController().setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
        }else {
            getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're saying that u don't status bar to open, then that isn't possible.

Comment: i need to disable, is it possible at least to receive the bar events? Like when is it taken down?

Answer (score 0):

You can't show and hide native status bar of android, the system doesn't allow you to do that. But  you can create your own customized status, then you can show it and hide it as you want.
Here and example:
custom_status.xml

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/mToolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/backButton"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/backButton"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/backButton" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backButton"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_solid"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/quantum_grey100"
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

in java code

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
final ListView lw = getListView();

if (view.getId() == lw.getId()) {
    final int currentFirstVisibleItem = lw.getFirstVisiblePosition();

    if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
        mIsScrollingUp = false;
        //mToolbar_container visible
    } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
        mIsScrollingUp = true;
        //mToolbar_container gone
    }
}
```

}